# Should we install a Package Locally or Globally with npm in React Native?

Tags: react-native, npm, package, npm-install

I am developing a React Native App, in which I have installed some Packages Locally and some Global and I can see Local and Global Packages via listing them with these Commands:

For Local Packages:

```
npm list
```

For Global Packages:

```
npm list -g
```

Right now, I am a bit Confused that whether I should install Packages Locally or Globally? What are the pros and cons of installing locally and globally? Also, which one is recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is where the package is stored on the disk and re-usage.

- Local packages are installed in your project directory (/node-modules) depending on your setup.
- Global packages are stored somewhere in your user directory. (Varies per system)

**Usually, modules used for building/generating files are usually installed globally, The rest are installed locally.**

this might be a good read to learn the differences: https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-global-or-local-packages